# Autofac not auto wiring properties to a custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to setup a class using Autofac autowired properties for a custom class which a controller calls. I have a setup a test project to show this. I have two projects in my solution. An MVC web application and a class library for services. Here's the code:

In the service project, AccountService.cs:

```
public interface IAccountService
{
    string DoAThing();
}

public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    public string DoAThing()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Now the rest is in the MVC web project.

Global.asax.cs

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AccountService).Assembly)
   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterType<Test>().PropertiesAutowired();

builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Test.cs:

```
public class Test
{
    //this is null when the var x = "" breakpoint is hit.
    public IAccountService _accountService { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {

    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var x = "";
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //this works fine
    public IAccountService _accountServiceTest { get; set; }
    //this also works fine
    public IAccountService _accountService { get; set; }

    public HomeController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var t = new Test();
        t.DoSomething();
        return View();
    }

//...
}
```

As you can see from the code above, both `_accountServiceTest` and `_accountService` work fine in the controller, but when setting a break point in `DoSomething()` method of the `Test.cs`, `_accountService` is always null, no matter what I put in the `global.asax.cs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create object with `new` autofac does not know anything about this object. So it's normal you always get null for `IAccountService` in `Test` class.

So proper way to this: 
Set Interface for Test class and register it. Then add this interface to your HomeController constructor.

```
public HomeController(IAccountService accountService,ITest testService)
```

Comment: This makes sense. I tested the changes and it works. I appreciated the help!